# make single word to 100% width

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make single word like "News" to make 100% width od div.
What I need is to set auto letter spacing, justify single words, I've got menu with items like:

- Home
- About
- News
- etc

I would like to have them fill 100% width

```
<div class="links">
  <a class="home" href="/home">Home</a>
  <a class="about" href="/about">About</a>
  <a class="news" href="/news">News</a>
</div>

.links {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
`font-size: 100%;`

Comment: this is not working for me